# Show that boring boolean circuit belongs to NP-complete class

Tags: complexity-theory, np-complete, circuits

> We say that a boolean circuit is boring if it returns the same
>   result for $>\frac34$ possible input, where we have $n$ input gates.
>   Hence, boring circuit returns the same output ($0$ or $1$) for
>   $>\frac34 2^n$ inputs.   Prove that checking if boolean circuit is boring is NP-complete

Can you help me? I have no idea how to start. I tried to reduce $3$-SAT but no result.

Comment: $2^n$ input gates means $2^{2^n}$ possible inputs, so you probably mean $n$ inputs. Is this homework? In any case, I'm guessing the statement is wrong, and that this problem is PP-hard, and so probably not in NP.

Comment: @Ariel I edited and fixed typo.  No, it is not homework. I practise for my exam./

Comment: @Ariel, in fact the best result I can see that this is in $\#P$. Or $PP$ can know any constant amount of bits?

Comment: @rus9384 This problem cannot be in #P, since #P is a class of functions and not decision problems.

Comment: @Ariel, I thought that every decision problem is also functional while controversal is false. The main argument is that functional machine also can output 0 or 1.

Comment: https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:Symbols#sharpp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a Boolean formula $\varphi$, let $x,y$ be two fresh variables, and consider the circuit computing the function
$$
x \lor y \lor \varphi.
$$
This circuit is boring iff $\varphi$ is satisfiable.

Comment: $\phi $ is 3CNF ?

Comment: If you want it to be. In fact it could be any formula, or really any circuit.

Comment: How many you cirucuit has input gates ?

Comment: The inputs to my circuit are all variables in $\varphi$ as well as the new variables $x,y$.

Comment: If half of the possible assignments satisfy $\varphi$, then the circuit for $x\lor y\lor \varphi$ is not boring.

Comment: No, that's not true. I'll let you figure that out. For example, $x \lor y \lor z$ is satisfied by 7/8 of the assignments.

Comment: What is a bit unsatisfactory is that this answer works for "> 3/4 2^n", and could be easily adapated for "> (k / 2^m) 2^n", but not for "> c 2^n" for other values c.

Comment: That shows NP-hardness but the question asks for completeness.

Comment: Ok, it was fairly easy. I didn't managed to solve it on my own because I think that I can't use alternative. Tell me please, what problem did you reduced here to problem from exercise ? I doesn't look like $k-SAT$ due to the fact you used alternative.

Comment: @HaskellFun, this was only NP-hardness, positive answer to your question is a big problem in CS. Satisfiability of any circuit is named as CircuitSAT - the first known (proved) NPC problem. Here $\varphi$ is a circuit that you have.

Comment: @DavidRicherby The problem probably isn't in NP (unless NP=PP).

Comment: What is difference between NP-hardness and NP-completness ?

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/9556/what-is-the-definition-of-p-np-np-complete-and-np-hard

Answer (score 6):

The problem is PP-hard. This means that unless the polynomial hierarchy collapses to NP, then deciding whether a circuit is boring is not in NP (and consequently is not NP-complete). The collapse follows from the fact that PP is closed under complement, so $\mathsf{PP=NP}$ implies $\mathsf{NP=coNP}$. We now show that deciding whether or not a circuit is boring is PP-hard.

Suppose $L\in PP$, then there exists a probabilistic polynomial Turing machine $M$ such that $x\in L \iff \Pr\left[M(x)=L(x)\right]>\frac{2}{3}$. Now consider the machine $M'$ which tosses two coins, if both output "heads" accept, otherwise execute $M$. If $x\in L$ then $M'$ accepts $x$ with probability $\frac{1}{4}+\frac{3}{4}\Pr\left[M(x)=L(x)\right]>\frac{3}{4}$. Now, let $C_x$ be the corresponding circuit for $M'$ on input $x$ (its inputs are the coins for $M'$), then $x\mapsto C_x$ is a reduction from $L$ to your problem, since $x\in L\iff C_x \text{ is boring}$. To see why, note that if $x\in L$ then $C_x$ accepts more than $\frac{3}{4}$ of the possible inputs, and if $x\notin L$ then $C_x$ accepts $\frac{1}{4}\le t\le \frac{3}{4}$ of the possible inputs.

In fact, your problem is PP-complete. To see why this language lies in PP, Let $L$ be the language of circuits who accept more than a $\frac{3}{4}$ fraction of their input, and $L'$ be the language of circuits who reject more than a $\frac{3}{4}$ fraction of their inputs. Clearly $L,L'\in PP$, and since PP is closed under union, deciding whether a circuit is boring, i.e is in $L\cup L'$, is in PP. Note that both here and in the above we used the fact that the constant in the definition of PP can be changed to any rational number.

If we want to avoid using closure properties of PP, then an argument along the following lines should work. Consider the machine $M$, which upon given an $n$-input circuit $C$, approximates the acceptance probability of $C$ by evaluating it on different uniformly distributed random length $n$ strings. Let $\hat{p}$ denote our evaluation. If $\hat{p}\ge\frac{1}{2}$, then $M$ evaluates $C$ on a random string and accept iff $C$ accepts, otherwise $M$ accepts iff $C$ rejects.
Let $E$ denote the event that $|p-\hat{p}|\le \frac{1}{4}$, where $p$ is the real acceptance probability of $C$. By evaluating $C$ on polynomially many strings, we can make sure that $\Pr\left[E\right]\ge 1-\frac{1}{2^{2n}}$. If $C$ is boring, then conditioned on $E$, $M$ obtained the right evaluation of the majority of $C$ and accepts with probability $>\frac{3}{4}$. Thus, if $C$ is boring $M$ accepts with probability $>\frac{3}{4}\left(1-\frac{1}{2^{2n}}\right)$. If $C$ isn't boring, then $C$ outputs either $0$ or $1$ with probability of at most $\frac{3}{4}-\frac{1}{2^n}$. Thus, regardless of our evaluation $\hat{p}$, $M$ accepts $C$ with probability of at most $\frac{3}{4}-\frac{1}{2^n}<\frac{3}{4}\left(1-\frac{1}{2^{2n}}\right)$, which puts our language in PP.

Comment: It is PP-complete as the answer states. The part about the problem being in PP was wrong, now fixed. Using the closure properties of PP here seems a little overkill, If something simpler comes up I will update. In any case, to be NP-complete the problem has to be in NP, and it probably isn't.

Comment: It is open question if $NP\stackrel{?}{=}PP$ to be precious.

Comment: Yes, and the answer is believed to be $\mathsf{NP\neq PP}$, since equality would imply a collapse of the polynomial hierarchy (by Toda's theorem).

Comment: Yuval has shown that the problem is NP-hard, even undecidable problems can be NP-hard (the halting problem for example).

Comment: @HaskellFun, it's correct: you can reduce problem X to any harder (at least as hard) problem Y and since PP-complete problems are harder than NP-complete, reduction is correct.